# Combining tables with missing columns into a single view

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, view

I have 2 tables Table 1 and Table 2. I need to combine them into one view. Column 1 in both tables identifies individual records.

## Table1

Column1  Column2  Column3

A               1               11
B               2               12
C               3               13
D               4               14

## Table2

Column1  Column4
A               21
A               22
A               23
A               24

I created view 1 as follows to get the below output

select column1, column2, column3, null as column4 from table1
union all
select column1, null as column2, null as column3, column4 from table2

## View1

Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4

A               1               11
B               2               12
C               3               13
D               4               14
A                                              21
A                                              22
A                                              23
A                                              24

I want to create a view that looks like this:

## Desired View

Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
A               1               11
B               2               12
C               3               13
D               4               14
A               1               11               21
A               1               11               22
A               1               11               23
A               1               11               24

Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: "combine them into one view" & "looks like this" are not clear descriptions of what you want. If you don't make the effort to clearly say what you want then you can't understand, reason, communicate or search. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. To describe a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a `join` as well:

```
select column1, column2, column3, null as column4
from table1
union all
select t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3, t2.column4
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t2.column1 = t1.column1;
```

If you didn't want:

```
A               1               11
```

Then a `left join` would suffice:

```
select t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3, t2.column4
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.column1 = t1.column1;
```

Comment: I need A 1 11, so i will stick with the join. Thanks for your answer!